# New release of Magento 2.0 block layout not displaying

Tags: php-5.4, extensions, magento2-dev-beta

Magento has released new version 2.0. I am trying to creating HelloWorld Module in Magento 2.0 . I have created controllers which is working fine. But I am having issue with displaying block in content area. Below is my code :

Excercise\HelloWorld\Block\HelloWorld.php

```
<?php
 namespace Excercise\HelloWorld\Block;
 class HelloWorld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
 {}
?>
```

Excercise\HelloWorld\view\frontend\layout\helloworld_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Lay   out/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Excercise\HelloWorld\Block\HelloWorld" name="helloworld" template="helloworld.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

Excercise\HelloWorld\view\frontend\template\helloworld.phtml

```
<h1>Welcome to Magento2 !</h1>
```

Please help me out to solve this issue.

Comment: Step 1 for me is making sure the module is being loaded at all. I should get around to updating my play extension at https://github.com/alankent/magento2-module-show-application-state to dev beta - it lists loaded modules. You can look at https://github.com/coldgreentea/m2extension as well which also lists them out.

Comment: Hi Alan..Module is loading perfectly. I have added it in etc/config.php file. I have followed https://www.ashsmith.io/2014/12/simple-magento2-controller-module/. Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to a pre stable version of Magento, more info here: http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/907/magento-2-questions-tagged-beta-alpha-pre-alpha-etc-quo-vadis